# How do I make parts of a string into different integers in C?

Tags: c

```
char date[10];
scanf("%s",&date);
```

Let's say I enter a date in format YYYY-MM-DD; for example:

```
2019-06-17
```

How do I extract the parts with the numbers and make them into integers like
`int year, month, day;`?

Comment: You need 11 bytes for `"YYYY-MM-DD"` ... don't forget the `'\0'`

Comment: Don't use `&` with arrays --- `scanf("%s", date);` -- arrays are implicitly converted to a pointer to their first element: just what scanf needs

Comment: If you are processing date/time information, consider whether POSIX [`strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) can be of use.  In this case, it is probably overkill, but it could be useful in other cases, especially if you also need to process time information.  It also probably isn't what your tutor had in mind for this exercise.

Comment: Wasn't an equivalent question (read numbers from a string) asked a hundred times before?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtol()`

```
char p[] = "2020-11-03";
char *q;
int n1 = strtol(p, &q, 10);
int n2 = strtol(q + 1, &q, 10);
int n3 = strtol(q + 1, 0, 10);
```

Needs error checking, validation, ...